# Pyspark error: "Undefined function: 'from_timestamp'

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying with spark.sql to fetch some data in pyspark from a hive view but every time it throws me the below error:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Undefined function: 'from_timestamp'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'default'.;
```

My settings on SparkSession.builder are these:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("home_office") \
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true") \
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict") \
    .config("hive.exec.compress.output=false", "false") \
    .config("spark.unsafe.sorter.spill.read.ahead.enabled", "false") \
    .config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", 1000)\
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such function `from_timestamp` in Spark SQL. If you're referring to the function in Impala, I believe the equivalent in Spark SQL is `date_format`.

Example usage:

```
select date_format(current_timestamp(), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a');

07/01/2021 08:37:11 AM
```

Comment: My query is: select * from office.office where work_date = ''20201218"..
Work_date is the partion field of the view which has been created with this "from_timstamp('yyyyMMdd') ". But this happens in hive.

Comment: @Thkas then you need to change the view to use `date_format` instead of `from_timestamp`, which is also invalid in hive.

Comment: Is there any other way to do the query without spark.sql ?

Comment: @Thkas you can read the hive table using `spark.read.table('table_name')` where `table_name` is the hive table name. I'm not sure if that works with views though.

Comment: If I want to run impala query in pyspark? Is the same procedure?

Comment: @Thkas I don't think you cannot run impala on spark. They are not compatible